# How to remove gnome-online-accounts integration?

Tags: debian, gnome3

I removed `gnome-online-accounts` and `gnome-online-miners` among other packages that I do not need on my Debian sid installation with Gnome 3. I still have "Online accounts" ("Облікові записи в інтернеті" in my language version) section in the control centre. The logos are missing, but it's still there. If I click on any of the options, a window with a login screen loads. How can I remove `gnome-online-accounts` properly, so that I do not have "Online accounts" section in the control centre altogether? Is it possible or is it intentionally not supported?

<s>Edit: I found a solution, which seems to work, which I posted as an answer below. But I will appreciate a better explained solution, recommendations, and explanation whether it is how the developers expected me to solve the issue.</s>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gnome settings draws panels from `/usr/share/applications/`. So, removing `gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop` removes the panel from the settings. The exact command I issued:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop
```

This permanently removes the panel from GNOME settings. If you ever want it back, you can reinstall `gnome-control-center`.

`gnome-control-center` package [recommends](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gnome-control-center) `gnome-online-accounts`. According to the [goals of GNOME Online Accounts](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts/Goals), the accounts:

> Must be used by the core GNOME system and apps

That implies that the accounts are necessary for the core GNOME applications to function properly and removing the accounts is not expected by GNOME developers, and their absence may be not supported by GNOME core applications.